# activiti 5.9 using a hibernate session possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, mybatis, activiti

is it possible to use activiti together with hibernate instead of mybatis? The case is that our actual project uses hibernate as persistence framework and we use jbpm 3 for the processes. In jbpm 3, it was possible to use a single hibernate session, so we get some benefits. Now we think about migration to activiti because the architecture is very great (spring, services, etc.), but on researching I found out that activiti uses mybatis for the persistence.

Is it possible that we can do the same things with activiti as with jbpm 3, regarding the persistence?
And if it is possible, what I need to do, to get it work.

EDIT:
I solve it for my needs and posted my soloution in the [activiti forum](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4360) for everyone who has the same problem like I had.
in short: sharing the session is not possible, but you can use the same transaction manager which helps you to rollback if an error occur.

Greetz cookie-exploit

Comment: are you using Spring in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mybatis can use the same transaction manager as hibernate (if both are running under Spring Framework)
- mybatis will not be able to participate in the Hibernate session

Comment: that's the way I now use it. I described it in the activiti forum ;)